# how to send voicemail in android

Tags: android

how to send voicemail in android

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for a program to "send voicemail in android", sorry.

Comment: But there is voicemail functionality on android phone...can you please tell me what procedure/protocol is followed by voicemailproviders to deliver voicemails to android users....I need to develop such application :/

Comment: @user1204089: That is not part of the Android SDK, sorry.